# How to use com.android.databinding in module(Android studio)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, data-binding, build.gradle

I want create a  library using `com.android.databinding: dataBinder`.

> build.gradle for project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        //gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8580
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> build.gradle for module :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'  // apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        generatedDensities = []
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
 }
```

I change 
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to  `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.But when I changed the code to the following error occured.

Error this :

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources] :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugUnitTestBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidDatabindingAdapters10Rc3Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidDatabindingLibrary10Rc3Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2320Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72320Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72320Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2320Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72320Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72320Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42320Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2320Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGithubAfollestadMaterialDialogsCore0856Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGithubOrangegangstersSwipy122Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComMakeramenRoundedimageview221Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDeKeyboardsurferAndroidWidgetCrouton185Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareMeZhanghaiAndroidMaterialprogressbarLibrary114Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources :app:processDebugManifest
>   :app:dataBindingLayoutsProcessDebugResources
>   :app:processDebugResources
>   D:\WorkSpace\Android\Java\Xomorod\Utility\src\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-fa\values-fa.xml
>   Warning:(70) warning: string 'app_name' marked untranslatable but
>   exists in locale 'fa' :app:dataBindingInfoClassProcessDebugResources
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidexInstrumentation101Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileLint :app:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   D:\WorkSpace\Android\Java\Xomorod\Utility\src\app\src\main\java\com\xomorod\utility\activities\common\MoreInfoAppActivity.java
>   **Error:(9, 39) error: package com.xomorod.utility.databinding does not
>   exist Error:(14, 3) error: cannot find symbol class**
>   ActivityMoreInfoAppBinding
>   D:\WorkSpace\Android\Java\Xomorod\Utility\src\app\src\main\java\com\xomorod\utility\activities\splash\SplashPresenterActivity.java
>   **Error:(13, 39) error: package com.xomorod.utility.databinding does not
>   exist Error:(25, 12) error: cannot find symbol class**
>   ActivitySplashBinding
>   D:\WorkSpace\Android\Java\Xomorod\Utility\src\app\src\main\java\com\xomorod\utility\section\fontManager\CardFont.java
>   **Error:(16, 39) error: package com.xomorod.utility.databinding does not
>   exist Error:(64, 9) error: cannot find symbol class CardFontBinding**
>   D:\WorkSpace\Android\Java\Xomorod\Utility\src\app\src\main\java\com\xomorod\utility\section\language\CardLanguage.java
>   **Error:(16, 39) error: package com.xomorod.utility.databinding does not
>   exist Error:(63, 9) error: cannot find symbol class**
>   CardLanguageBinding
>   D:\WorkSpace\Android\Java\Xomorod\Utility\src\app\src\main\java\com\xomorod\utility\section\market\CardApp.java
>   **Error:(15, 39) error: package com.xomorod.utility.databinding does not
>   exist Error:(58, 9) error: cannot find symbol class CardAppBinding**
>   D:\WorkSpace\Android\Java\Xomorod\Utility\src\app\src\main\java\com\xomorod\utility\section\themeManager\CardTheme.java
>   **Error:(16, 39) error: package com.xomorod.utility.databinding does not
>   exist Error:(63, 9) error: cannot find symbol class CardThemeBinding**
>   D:\WorkSpace\Android\Java\Xomorod\Utility\src\app\src\main\java\com\xomorod\utility\activities\common\AbstractMainActivity.java
>   **Error:(25, 15) error: attribute value must be constant Error:(28, 15)
>   error: attribute value must be constant Error:(31, 15) error:
>   attribute value must be constant**
>   D:\WorkSpace\Android\Java\Xomorod\Utility\src\app\src\main\java\com\xomorod\utility\activities\common\MoreApplicationActivity.java
>   **Error:(25, 15) error: attribute value must be constant Error:(28, 15)
>   error: attribute value must be constant**
>   D:\WorkSpace\Android\Java\Xomorod\Utility\src\app\src\main\java\com\xomorod\utility\activities\common\SettingsActivity.java
>   **Error:(230, 19) error: attribute value must be constant Error:(301,
>   19) error: attribute value must be constant Error:(383, 19) error:
>   attribute value must be constant**
>   D:\WorkSpace\Android\Java\Xomorod\Utility\src\app\src\main\java\com\xomorod\utility\section\market\MoreAppFragment.java
>   **> Error:(37, 15) error: attribute value must be constant Error:(40, 15)
>   error: attribute value must be constant Error:(43, 15) error:
>   attribute value must be constant Note: Some input files use or
>   override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for
>   details. Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>    Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details**.Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 12.413 secs
>   Information:24 errors Information:1 warning Information:See complete
>   output in console

Comment: have you found a solutions for this?

Answer (score 6):

Follow the guide here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html

You must add `dataBinding.enabled = true` to the `android` section. You should also use android gradle plugin 1.5.0 or later.

You don't need the `apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'` anymore either. Data binding is now included into the android gradle plugin.

Comment: I remove apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding' occurred this errpr. Error:Unable to find method 'android.databinding.tool.LayoutXmlProcessor.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/databinding/tool/writer/JavaFileWriter;IZLandroid/databinding/tool/LayoutXmlProcessor$OriginalFileLookup;)

Comment: which version of android gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: Also, do you have jcenter in your dependencies?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

Comment: I keep getting an error: `Error:Could not find com.android.databinding:library:1.1.
Required by`

Comment: That is likely due to your needing to upgrade the Android Support Repository. The latest revision is 30.

Answer (score 3):

Only add

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

if you are using gradle 2.0 or later. 
for example:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```